# Connect() to .sock failed, no such file

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a Django app that runs fine on localhost with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8443`.

Now, I have a server on which I wish to run the app. To do so, i followed [this guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Here I set up a virtualenv, configured uWSGI and nginx. As far as I can tell, everything is set up correctly, yet when i try to reach my address it returns `502`. The following error is found in the `error.log`

```
2017/07/13 11:24:11 [crit] 4825#0: *1 connect() to unix:/home/django/sample/sample.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 131.180.112.131, server: annotatie01.io.tudelft.nl, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/data_nfs/data_collection_project.sock:", host: "annotatie01.io.tudelft.nl:8443", referrer: "http://annotatie01.io.tudelft.nl:8443/"
```

It appears that the .sock file is never created. I can not find it in the directories either. Where should this file be created?

I've seen a few questions related to this, but for those it appears that either the `.socks` does exist, or they're not using `uWSGI`

**uWSGI:**

File : `/etc/uwsgi/sites/data_collection_project.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
project = data_collection_project
base = /data_nfs

chdir = %(base)/%(project)
home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
module = %(project).wsgi:application

master = true
processes = 2

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true
```

File: `/etc/init/uwsgi.conf`

```
description "uWSGI"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]
respawn

env UWSGI=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi
env LOGTO=/var/log/uwsgi.log

exec $UWSGI --master --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites --die-on-term --uid django --gid www-data --logto $LOGTO
```